# How do you create Winform user control that supports multiple items like a listbox

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I think I understand the basics of create winforms user control.  I can do Add New and select user control and that will give me a design surface and designer file and code-behind file etc.  And then I could change it to inherit from something other than UserControl (like listbox or text box).

The thing that is different for me this time is the user control needs to be a list control (like a list box) that can be data-bound and with two data-bindable controls in it (two combo boxes).

I am not sure where to start? Can anybody reference a document or some obvious bit in the tooling that I am missing that will make it quick and easy?  Any approaches I can take like extending an existing control.  Any gotchas I need to be aware of?

Thanks.

Seth

**EDIT**
I have decided to take a different approach.  I am leaving the question up, though.  This is clearly difficulty than I had guessed.  WPF is not an option for me unfortunately.  Just gonna use a data grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And then I could change it to inherit from something other than UserControl (like listbox or text box).

This is where you make a mistake...when you derive from UserControl you shouldn't change the inheritance. Inheriting from UserControl gives you exactly the possibility to place multiple different controls on your design surface (like a listbox and two comboboxes). These combined controls make your unique (user)control which you should give a self-explanatory name. understand it? **It's really simple, very powerfull, very reusable, fun and we use it a lot.**

A good reference may be this: [Microsoft walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [MonthPicker (simple)](http://ivision.wordpress.com/2006/12/25/month-picker-an-user-control-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to override the list control to match your requirements. Not easily anyways. However there are alternatives:

Since the control has its own events you can override the render, and draw the visual characteristics of what looks like a list control. Next you have to create delegates and event handlers so that your control can signal to the rest of the form that something happened inside it.

The next alternative is to do the same as I described above, however by using WPF. WPF has a lot more flexibility in regard to custom UI.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user control, add a listbox and set it to dock = full (or whatever fits your design needs).

override the DataSource property and have it call a method that will combine the sources into a single source then bind/rebind that single source to your list.

There are downfalls to this, but it's one way.

The other is to not create a user control but to just combine all of your sources into a single source and then bind that to the listbox control.

WPF wouldn't help in this situation.